# Facing issue in optimization/calibration in R using different of algorithms

Tags: r, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, simulated-annealing

I am new to optimization/calibration, hence I want to explain every detail of it. So it will be a very long post, kindly bear with me :)

I have been trying to calibrate the Heston (1993) model for option prices using high-frequency data. But I am encountering certain issues.

I have 5 parameters to estimate (kappa, theta, sigma, rho, v0). Below is the approach that I am following:

1. Calculate (guess) the initial value of the parameters to be input into the optimization algorithm. I have done this with a hit and trial method.
2. Use the `callHestoncf` of the `NMOF` package to calculate the option prices.
3. Calculate the difference of the market price of the options and the prices calculated from (2)
4. The difference obtained from (3) is input into the optimization function.

Below is the dput of the data that I am using:

> dput(head(temp))
>       structure(list(EXPDATE = structure(c(1296066600, 1296066600, 
>       1296066600, 1296066600, 1296066600, 1296066600), class = c("POSIXct", 
>       "POSIXt")), STRIKE = c(6400L, 6400L, 6400L, 6400L, 6400L, 6400L
>       ), TTE = c(17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17), SPOT = c(6146.39759036145, 
>       6146.16962025316, 6148.28617021277, 6147.04015151515, 6140.85952380952, 
>       6139.94405940594), RATE = c(0.0745855265628133, 0.0745855265628133, 
>       0.0745855265628133, 0.0745855265628133, 0.0745855265628133, 0.0745855265628133
>       ), DIV = c(0.0101, 0.0101, 0.0101, 0.0101, 0.0101, 0.0101), DATE = c("2011-01-04", 
>       "2011-01-04", "2011-01-04", "2011-01-04", "2011-01-04", "2011-01-04"
>       ), QUANT = c(2000L, 2400L, 1600L, 2500L, 2000L, 1500L), PRICE = c(16.05, 
>       16, 15.9, 16.4, 15, 15)), .Names = c("EXPDATE", "STRIKE", "TTE", 
>       "SPOT", "RATE", "DIV", "DATE", "QUANT", "PRICE"), row.names = c(NA, 
>       6L), class = "data.frame")

And below is the function to calculate the objective to be minimised:

```
#callHestoncf <- function(S,X,tau,r,q,v0,vT,rho,k,sigma,implVol = FALSE)
#input = [kappa theta sigma rho v0]
function(initial, df){
    hdiff = rep(0, nrow(df))
    if (2*initial[1]*initial[2]-initial[3]^2<0){    ##condition on parameters
            initial[1]=initial[1]+0.1
            initial[2]=initial[2]+0.05}
    else if (2*initial[1]*initial[2]-initial[3]^2>=0){
            for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
                    hdiff[i] = abs((df['PRICE'][i,] - callHestoncf(df['SPOT'][i,], df['STRIKE'][i,], df['TTE'][i,]/250, df['RATE'][i,], 
                                                                   df['DIV'][i,], initial[5], initial[2], initial[4], initial[1], initial[3])))
            }
            #return(as.numeric(max(hdiff)))
            return(as.numeric(mean(hdiff)))
            #return(as.numeric(hdiff))
    }}
```

I have used the following functions for optimization:
`nlminb` (stats)
`DEoptim` (DEoptim)
`optim` (stats) - methods "L-BFGS-B", "SANN"
`GenSA` (GenSA)

Below is a function which I've written to calculate the error in pricing using the optimized parameters.

```
calcdiff=function(df, initial2){
    A=rep(0,nrow(df))
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
    A[i] = abs((df['PRICE'][i,] - callHestoncf(df['SPOT'][i,], df['STRIKE'][i,], df['TTE'][i,]/250, df['RATE'][i,], 
                                               df['DIV'][i,], initial2[5], initial2[2], initial2[4], initial2[1], initial2[3])))

}    
return (A)}
```

And below is how I call it

```
initial2=c(0.3131582,0.01,0.2480684,-0.7201562,0.2845104)   ####parameter set obtained after optimization
ans = calcdiff(temp, initial2)
summary(ans)
```

Below is how I call the optimization functions:

```
initial = c(0.6, 0.01, 0.15, -0.5, 0.0196)
lb = c(0.01, 0.01, 0.01, -1, 0.01)
ub = c(1, 0.4, 1, 1, 0.4)
soln = nlminb(start=initial,objective=hestdiff,lower=lb, upper=ub, df=temp)

soln = DEoptim(hestdiff,lower=lb, upper=ub, df=temp, DEoptim.control(trace=FALSE, CR=0.7))

soln = optim(par = initial, fn = hestdiff, gr = NULL, method = "SANN", lower = lb, upper = ub, df = temp, control = list(maxit = 30000, trace = TRUE))

soln = optim(par = initial, fn = hestdiff, gr = NULL, method = "L-BFGS-B", lower = lb, upper = ub, df = temp, control = list(trace = 2))

soln=GenSA(par=initial, fn=hestdiff, lower=lb, upper=ub, df=temp,control=list(smooth=FALSE, verbose=TRUE))
```

Using the function `nlminb`, I could get a reasonably accurate estimate of the parameters, and a low pricing error (mean=Rs.3.7, median=Rs.3.5), but as I understand, it is a local optimization approach, hence the choice of the inputs is very critical. Also, as I have to do this calibration over many days, it is not very feasible to do hit and trial for the initial estimates every day. Hence I was looking at a global optimizer.

Using `DEoptim` (with the the same values as above): It runs 200 iterations, and results in the parameters: c(0.7239727, 0.01, 0.5224246, 0.9484754, 0.2316809). Using these values, I get exorbitant errors (mean=Rs 211, median=Rs 208).

Using `L-BFGS-B` has similar issues as `nlminb`

When I use `SANN` or `GenSA`, which are global optimizers, I get the below error after few iterations

```
Error in integrate(P2, lower = 0, upper = Inf, S, X, tau, r, q, v0, vT,  : 
  the integral is probably divergent
```

I know the error occurs because the integral is not solvable for certain values in the parameter range. But shouldnt there be an inbuilt mechanism to ignore such cases?
The issue can be manifolds here, although I feel it is not because of points 1-4 below:
1. Am I calculating the objective correctly?
2. Am I RETURNING the correct objective function to the optimization algo? (function 'hestdiff' above)
3. Is there an issue in the way that I calculating my pricing error? (function 'calcdiff' above)
4. Is there an issue in the way I am calling the optimization functions?
5. Are there any other optimization functions that I can/should use?
6. Finally, what should I do to make this work :)

Thanks for bearing with me till the end. Even after spending days, I cant find a way forward. It would really be great if anyone can help me with this.

Thanks and Regards,
Shivam

Comment: Why would you want an unsolvable integral to be "ignored" ?  Perhaps what you are thinking of is `trycatch` , to let you be aware of failing cases without terminating the entire script.

Comment: Ignored because the function is not expected to be defined for all the possible combinations of the parameters. Hence, if such combination arises, we ignore that and move on, as it is not going to be the optimal solution.